# Bind Value to KEY in Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

In my controller, I am Fetching The data and binding it to my VIEW BAG.

```
var GetStudentName = new SelectList(_wOService.GetName()
.ToDictionary(us => us.ID, us => us.Name), "Key", "Value");
ViewBag.GetStudentName = GetStudentName ;
```

Here is my CSHTML PAGE

```
<select id="SearchName" name="SearchName" asp-items="@ViewBag.GetStudentName " disabled class="form-control GetStudentName ">
<option value=""> Select </option>
</select>
```

Now When I run the application In dropdown it shows me data like

**Key    Value**

1      XYZ

2      PQR

3      ASD

4      ZXD

Means It shows me NAME And Bind the ID to Dropdown,
***BUT* I want to BIND VALUE data to KEY**

**Key    Value**

XYZ     XYZ

PQR     PQR

ASD     ASD

ZXD     ZXD

BECAUSE IN MY **SP AND VIEW IN SQL** I am FETCHING THE BASED ON THE NAME NOT ID/KEY.

Comment: Did you try `.ToDictionary(us => us.Name, us => us.Name)`?

Comment: The question title is all wrong. Because connecting a value to a key is essentially what a dictionary does. You are building a selectlist. That's something differently. Just make a custom key for the selectlist. P.s. what does you want the value to be, i mean the one that is actually returned for the selected option?

Comment: to me it looks like you want a HashSet?

Comment: @YongShun Yes tried but did not work

Comment: SOLVED THANK YOU FOR GIVING ME Suggestion